# Loading cursor in standalone build

Tags: unity-game-engine

sorry if it's a bit off-topic as it may not be code-related, but I'm facing a weird issue.

Everything is fine in the editor, but when I build my application as standalone, I have the windows loading cursor that "load" infinitely. It's happening as soon as the app is running, even on the main menu when no script are running.

What could be causing this ? I've no clue on how I could find the problem (like see what scripts are currently running for instance). It's not causing any issue, but it's just weird to see the loading cursor.

I'm also facing a weird aspect ratio (only in my computer, it may be related to the fact that I've two screen that don't use the same aspect ratio 16:9 and 16:10) but on the player settings, I've only set 16:9 as supported.

Here's my player settings :

[image: settings]

I've tried "Default is native resolution" as well as  checking more supported aspect ratio, nothing seems to fix this glitch.

Thanks !

Comment: whats in the log file when you run it from the build? what happens if you connect a debugger to it?

Comment: I don't think there is a log file (at least I can't find it). I tried to attach the profiler / debugger, but couldn't see what could be the problem

Comment: Ok I found it, there is a lot of stuff coming from the XR plugin but not sure if that's related in any way with this "loading" cursor : https://pastebin.com/82NsCKSf

Comment: Found something (but that's even more weird), if I click somewhere else / alt tab and come back to the application, it restores the normal cursor instead of the loading one...

Comment: unfortunately i cant view pastebin from work (its apparently the work of the devil) ..

Comment: https://textuploader.com/1oupo Does that work for you ? Sucks to be blocked on pastebin tho ahah

Comment: So, if I do Win+Alt+Arrow to switch the application to my other monitor, it fixes the aspect ratio bug, if I put it back it works as well (changing monitor fixes this problem, but I need to fix it without this hack). The hack of alt tabing to remove the loading cursor however only works for me and not my colleague...

Comment: well the reason its not working is NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at UIManager.SetMainMenuActive()" so somewhere is an untrapped error

Comment: I fixed that just after sending the log and it's not changing anything (I just made a small change in awake/start that led to this). It's not related unfortunately :/

Comment: what happens then if you disable the UImanager all together as it also gives other warnings? if stuff starts happening it would suggest you can narrow it down

Comment: Still the same (and the only warning is just to tell you not to use canvas on VR, which I'm not anyway because the application is usable with and without VR, and I remove the canvas when Vr is enabled).

Comment: only suggestion left if debugging wasnt helping, add a crapton of debug statements... see what happens and where its going

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what happened when building application. Check if editor scripts of any plugin do stuff.
2. It may because PlayerPref has saved the resolution setting.

   - try `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Screenmanager Resolution Use Native", 1);`
   - or forced change resolution `Screen.SetResolution(1920, 1080, true);`